# How fix issue with platforms on android-sdk on linux?

Tags: scala, android-sdk-tools

Hello need advice how fix this issue:

`failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /opt/android-sdk`

what i have:

`docker container on ubuntu 15.04, Scala 2.11.8, Java 1.8, sbt 0.13.11, adnroid-sdk r23.0.2 or 24.4.1 ( i try both version )`

 i store sdk, sbt and scala in `/opt/`

issue: when i try to build project with gradle I get an error

`failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /opt/android-sdk`

how i can list sdk platforms - or what i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything in `/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-23`? If not, that means you only installed the core tools, but you still need to install the platform SDK, build tools, etc. There should be an executable at `/opt/android-sdk/tools/android` that starts a GUI and lets you choose what additional SDK packages to install.

Comment: I do not have GUI - only cli

Comment: Then `android list sdk --extended` and `android update sdk --no-ui -a --filter tools,platform-tools,android-23,build-tools-23.0.2` are your friends.